# How to realize cascade methods in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have simple CRUD application with author, genre, comment and book domain entities. Here is the problem: I can't realize update method properly.
I have controller for each entity with put mapping which invokes service's update method with arguments and returns it's result. But then I manually test it, there is not effect. It looks like these methods are not even invoked. I know that reactive streams are lazy, but it should be executed anyway or I missed something.
Here is my BookService update method.

```
public Mono<Tuple2<Flux<Comment>, Book>> updateBook(String id, String title, String authorNameParameter,
                                                        String genreNameParameter) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id)
                .map(b -> commentRepository.saveAll(commentRepository.findByBook_Title(b.getTitle())
                        .flatMap(c -> Mono.just(c.setBook(title)))))
                .zipWith(bookRepository.findById(id).flatMap(b -> getAuthor(authorNameParameter)
                            .flatMap(a -> Mono.just(b.setAuthor(a)))
                            .flatMap(book -> Mono.just(book.setTitle(title)))
                            .flatMap(book -> getGenre(genreNameParameter)
                                    .flatMap(g -> Mono.just(book.setGenre(g))))));
    }
```

And same at the AuthorService:

```
public Mono<Tuple2<Flux<Book>, Author>> updateAuthor(String id, String name) {
        return authorRepository.findById(id)
                .map(a -> bookRepository.findByAuthor_Id(a.getId())
                        .flatMap(b -> Mono.just(b.setAuthor(a.setName(name)))).flatMap(bookRepository::save))
                .zipWith(authorRepository.findById(id).flatMap(a -> Mono.just(a.setName(name)))
                        .flatMap(authorRepository::save));
    }
```

And GenreService:

```
public Mono<Tuple2<Flux<Book>, Genre>> updateGenre(String id, String name) {
        return genreRepository.findById(id)
                .map(g -> bookRepository.findByGenre_Id(g.getId())
                        .flatMap(b -> Mono.just(b.setGenre(g.setName(name)))).flatMap(bookRepository::save))
                .zipWith(genreRepository.findById(id).flatMap(g -> Mono.just(g.setName(name)))
                        .flatMap(genreRepository::save));
    }
```

AuthorService and GenreService updates author/genre entities but do not updating book, BookService doesn't do anything. I just want to get related entities updated (genre -> book, author -> book, book -> comment).

Setter are just creating new instance with changes, it is more conveniently for reactive programming.

**So the final question**: how to implement cascade updating with Spring WebFlux in my case.
May be there is some misunderstanding of the reactive concept from me.

Comment: the code is quite hard to follow, try splitting it up into several functions and you will probably find where you are missing a return.

Comment: That was really helpful :)
I just stuck in this mess